# Why can't I import sprintf-js in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a TypeScript file into which I'm importing third-party libraries.

```
import * as _ from 'lodash'; // Works great!
import * as moment from 'moment'; // Works great!
import {vsprintf} from 'sprintf-js'; // Compiler error
```

As my comments explain, the first two imports work great, but the sprintf-js import does not. I get the following compiler error:

> Error TS2307: Cannot find module 'sprintf-js'.

Without a doubt, I have `sprintf-js` inside of my `node_modules` folder. I'm not very knowledgeable about node modules. I'm guessing that the [sprintf-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sprintf-js) libarary does something different than lodash or moment and that TypeScript doesn't like it. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add a typing definition for `sprintf-js`. Depending on your setup - if you have TSD installed and setup with your project, it would be a case of running:

```
tsd  query sprintf-js --action save
```

otherwise, you can have a read here:

http://definitelytyped.org/

or simply download the typing definition and include it in the project root folder:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/master/sprintf-js/sprintf-js.d.ts

Comment: Yes, that's it! I had the wrong definition file. I had `sprintf` instead of `sprintf-js`.

Comment: tsd is deprecated (npm WARN deprecated tsd@0.6.5: TSD is deprecated in favor of Typings)
see https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd/issues/269 for more information
As such, you can use the following command to add a typing definition with Typings:
`typings install sprintf-js --ambient --save`